# Why is my PHP function not returning a value?

Tags: php

This function is meant to sanitise a given value but instead it outputs "n-a" as if no value was specified. It has to be the simplest issue but right this moment it has me beat.

```
function slug($text){ 

  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^pLd]+~u', '-', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-w]+~', '', $text);

  if (empty($text))
  {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}
```

I'd appreciate some input.

Comment: **Where** does it become empty? Have you tried dumping the variable as you go along? (after replace, after trim, after strtolower, after second replace)

Comment: `$text = preg_replace('~[^-w]+~', '', $text);` this removes everything other than `-` and `w`. I think your string does not have `-` or `w`. so you are getting empty string. try to rewrite regex here

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your first regex which seems to be incorrect, should be,

```
// replace non letter or digits by -
$text = preg_replace('~[^\w\d]+~u', '-', $text);
```

**[*Working Demo.*](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VnHTnr)**

Comment: I think he meant `\pL\d` (aka. unicode letter/digit).

Comment: @h2ooooooo - adding backslashes solved my problem i.e. first regex to \pL\d and the second to \w

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using mb_string library instead of iconv. Its a better library.
2. At each instance try var_dump or echo to make sure the return of the data.